# How can I get the difference between a negative and positive number, or two negatives, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to compare the magnitudes of stars, and for that, I need the difference between them, but right now I can't figure out how to factor in whether the first magnitude is negative and the second positive, or vice-versa, or *both* negative... I should mention I really don't know a lot about coding, or maths for that matter.

Comment: Post few sample data then show your desired output.

Comment: @Harun24hr Well, say I want to get the difference between 5 and -10, then -5 and -10, and then -5 and 10. The differences should be 15, 5, and 15 again.

Comment: Do you just need the absolute value of the difference? Something like `=ABS(A1-B1)`?

Comment: @yshavit I believe so. Harun has answered, but thank-you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, you just want difference between maximum and minimum. Try-

```
=MAX(A2:B2)-MIN(A2:B2)
```

Use the following formula to spill results dynamically.

```
=BYROW(A2:B,LAMBDA(x,MAX(x)-MIN(x)))
```

[image]